# Bypass validation rule for after insert Trigger

Tags: apex

I have a validation rule for the `Opportunity` object where in if the `Opportunity` has a `OpportunityLineItem` certain custom fields cannot be edited from the `UI. Now I have a Trigger in the`OpportunityLineItem`where in If I try to Add/Edit/Delete an`OpportunityLineItem`that is linked in it's`Opportunity`It will calculate those certain fields in the`Opportunity` object.

I already created a bypass checkbox in the `Opportunity` object which is in it's default value = true.

Can Someone Guide me to complete this? Thank you in advance

This is my Validation Rule in The `Opportunity` Object

```
    (HasOpportunityLineItem && 
(ISCHANGED( Total_List_Price__c))  || 
(ISCHANGED( Total_End_User_Price__c)) ||
(ISCHANGED( Total_End_User_Price_Discount__c)) || 
(ISCHANGED( Total_Standard_Price__c)) || 
(ISCHANGED( Total_Standard_Price_Discount__c)) ||
(ISCHANGED( Total_SPR_Price__c)) || 
(ISCHANGED( Total_SPR_Price_Discount__c)) || 
(ISCHANGED( Total_Price__c)) || 
(ISCHANGED( Total_Price_Discount__c)) ||
(ISCHANGED( Total_SPR_Margin__c)) ) &&  dummyCheckbox__c == True
```

and this is my Trigger in the `OpportunityLineItem` Object

```
trigger TotalOpportunityProductTrigger on OpportunityLineItem (after insert, after update, after delete) {

Opportunity Oppor = new Opportunity();
LPGCalculatorSettings__c objCalSetting = LPGCalculatorSettings__c.getValues('RollupTriggerSwitch');

if(objCalSetting.value__c){
TotalOpportunityProductTriggerHandler tp = new TotalOpportunityProductTriggerHandler();

if(Trigger.isInsert && Trigger.isAfter){

tp.TotalField(Trigger.new);
oppor.dummyCheckbox__c = False;
}
else if (Trigger.isUpdate && Trigger.isAfter){

tp.TotalField(Trigger.new);
oppor.dummyCheckbox__c = False;
}
else if(Trigger.isDelete && Trigger.isAfter){

tp.TotalField(Trigger.old);
oppor.dummyCheckbox__c = False;
}
}
}
```

Can someone help me to complete this one? I don't even know if I am in the right path. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

There are two solution here. Instead of using Validation rule you can do same validation using trigger. It will give you better control.

Second is you need to set checkbox value false for all record not for just a single record

```
if(Trigger.isInsert && Trigger.isAfter){
//you need to set the checkbox field false here
//but as this code run in After syntax so first you need to query all Opportunity and then set it to false.
// and you need to do this in all if conditions.
tp.TotalField(Trigger.new);

}
```

This is not a recommend approach. Because you need to handle recursive trigger as well.

So Create a Trigger on Opportunity and put the validation there and a create a static Boolean variable and set it to false from `Opportunity Line Item trigger` and in `Opportunity trigger` check if this Boolean variable is false don't run the validation.

Comment: @TushurSharma. I found simpler solution where in I'll just create a workflow rule that will change the dummy checkbox back to false so that the validation rule will run again but I can't seem to make it work. Can you help me?

Comment: @JMDF check [Order Of Execution](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_triggers_order_of_execution.htm) Validation rule come first then WF so before your WF update the checkbox Validation rule will give error and will stop the execution. So I don't think this approach will work.

Comment: Well Actually my plan is to do an before insert, before delete , before update where in it will change the dummyCheckbox = True, so that It will bypass the validation rule right and then create a workflow rule that will return the checkbox to false every a record is added, edited , deleted. Do you think this will work? By the way my Trigger is in after insert, after delete, after update. @TusharSharma

Comment: @JMDF yes it will work but as you update the checkbox then your trigger will run again and before trigger again set it to false. So you need to handle that.

Comment: Hi @TusharSharma can you help me with this one so that I can trying doing my proposed solution to you? http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/146052/validation-rule-using-and-function-trying-to-skip-running-validation

Comment: Hi Sharma Can you explain more elaborately your solution. I guess I'll just try this one.

Comment: Hi can you guide me? I am kinda stuck with this one and I need to finish this.

Comment: @JMDF you can create this validation on Opportunity Trigger and there you can easily control when you need to run the trigger.  Let me know what point you didn't understand.