# Bypass Validation Rule using Custom Settings

Tags: apex, formula, validation, validation-rule

I have a `Validation Rule` on the `Opportunity` object where in if the `Opportunity` has a `OpportunityLineItem` certain custom fields cannot be edited from the UI. Now I have an `Apex Trigger` on the `OpportunityLineItem` where if I try to Add/Edit/Delete an `OpportunityLineItem`, it will calculate those fields on the `Opportunity` record.

I already created a `Hierarchy Custom Setting` called `MyCustomSetting__c` that has a checkbox field called `Skip_Validation__c`. Why can I not bypass the `Validation Rule`?

**Validation Rule**

```
 HasOpportunityLineItem && 
(ISCHANGED( Total_List_Price__c))  || 
(ISCHANGED( Total_End_User_Price__c)) ||
(ISCHANGED( Total_End_User_Price_Discount__c)) || 
(ISCHANGED( Total_Standard_Price__c)) || 
(ISCHANGED( Total_Standard_Price_Discount__c)) ||
(ISCHANGED( Total_SPR_Price__c)) || 
(ISCHANGED( Total_SPR_Price_Discount__c)) || 
(ISCHANGED( Total_Price__c)) || 
(ISCHANGED( Total_Price_Discount__c)) ||
(ISCHANGED( Total_SPR_Margin__c)) &&  NOT($Setup.myCustomSetting__c.Skip_Validation__c)
```

**Trigger**

```
trigger TotalOpportunityProductTrigger on OpportunityLineItem (before insert, before update, before delete , after insert, after update, after delete) {


LPGCalculatorSettings__c objCalSetting = LPGCalculatorSettings__c.getValues('RollupTriggerSwitch');

MyCustomSetting__c tempSkipValidation = MyCustomSetting__c.getInstance();


if(tempSkipValidation == null) {
  tempSkipValidation = new MyCustomSetting__c();
    }

tempSkipValidation.Skip_Validation__c = true;
    upsert tempSkipValidation;

if(objCalSetting.value__c){
TotalOpportunityProductTriggerHandler tp = new TotalOpportunityProductTriggerHandler();



if(Trigger.isInsert && Trigger.isAfter){

tp.TotalField(Trigger.new);

       }
else if (Trigger.isUpdate && Trigger.isAfter){

tp.TotalField(Trigger.new);

       }
else if(Trigger.isDelete && Trigger.isAfter){

tp.TotalField(Trigger.old);

    }
}

            tempSkipValidation.Skip_Validation__c = false;
            update tempSkipValidation;
}
```

I already checked and reviewed the Apex order of execution and I don't think that it will affect my code.

Comment: Do you mean you don't want user to edit the field from UI but should be able to edit it from trigger ?

Comment: @AtulRajguru9 Well basically at first The user Can edit the fields through the UI but once that there is a OpportunityLineItem, the user can't anymore and can only edit those fields through the trigger that will run in the OpportunityLineItem when I insert,edit,delete a product.

Comment: As per this doc,

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_triggers_order_of_execution.htm

Order of Execution is 

...>Validation Rules >.....> Triggers

So I guess you will not be able to bypass "Validation Rules" via trigger code

I could be wrong and someone can correct me if so.

Comment: @ZenSeeker, that's exactly right. Validation rules execute before trigger so this will not work.

Comment: Notice that `before` triggers fire before `Validation Rules`. It can be done.

Comment: This is now the third time in 24 hours that you've asked pretty much the same question ([first question](http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/145938/bypass-validation-rule-for-after-insert-trigger), [second question](http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/146052/validation-rule-using-and-function-trying-to-skip-running-validation)). Is there a particular reason why this needed to be spread over 3 questions? -1 from me.

Comment: Alternatively, asking so many questions on the same topic may mean that this is an [X-Y problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). From that link: `That is, you are trying to solve problem X, and you think solution Y would work, but instead of asking about X when you run into trouble, you ask about Y.`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here is a case where using `AND`/`OR` is much more clear about which operations you are joining with your logical operators. You may have also confused yourself here with incorrect parentheses and ordering.

Logical operators just join clauses in order.

If you write **`A && B || C || D && E`**, it will be true if only `C` is true, or if `A & B` is true or if `D & E` is true. It's equivalent to **`(A && B) || C || (D && E)`**.

In contrast **`A && (B || C || D) && E`** would only return true if `A` and `E` are true and at least one of `B`/`C`/`D` are true.

In light of the above, what you have written is equivalent to:

```
OR(
    AND(
        HasOpportunityLineItem,
        ISCHANGED(Total_List_Price__c)
    )
    ISCHANGED(...),
    ISCHANGED(...),
    AND(
        ISCHANGED(Total_SPR_Margin__c),
        NOT($Setup.myCustomSetting__c.Skip_Validation__c)
    )
)
```

But this validation rule doesn't match up with what you want at all! I believe what you really want is:

```
AND(
    HasOpportunityLineItem, NOT($Setup.MySetting__c.Skip_Validation__c),
    OR(
        ISCHANGED(...),
        ISCHANGED(...)
    )
)
```

Comment: Another consequence of this error is that you should, for instance, not be able to change `Total_Price__c` even if `HasOpportunityLineItem` is false.